# Typescript does not recognize condition

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code:

```
type HTTPGet = {
    url: string
    params?: Record<string, unknown>
    result: unknown
}
export const httpGet = <D extends HTTPGet>(url: D['url'], params: D['params'] = undefined): Promise<D['result']> => {
    let path = url
    if (params !== undefined) {
        path += '?' + toHTTPQueryString(params);
    }
    return fetch(path, {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
}
```

After condition `params !== undefined` I call toHTTPQueryString, which accepts only Record<string, unknown> type.
But I have the TypeScript error:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'D["params"]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, unknown>'.   Type 'Record<string, unknown> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, unknown>'.     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, unknown>'.

Why I get this message? TypeScript should understand that I have condition `params !== undefined` and remains only `Record<string, unknown>` type, that is assignable to `toHTTPQueryString` parameter type.

Comment: What is the signature of `toHTTPQueryString`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting one.  It's obviously a "mistake" on the part of Typescript to properly refine the type.

The error boils down to how typescript evaluates the type guard.  Consider these two user-defined type guards.  They both do the same check, but they define their signature differently.

```
const isDefined1 = <T extends any>(value: T | undefined): value is T => { 
  return value !== undefined;
}
const isDefined2 = <T extends any>(value: T): value is Exclude<T, undefined> => { 
  return value !== undefined;
}
```

```
if (isDefined1(params)) {
  path += '?' + toHTTPQueryString(params); // error
}
if (isDefined2(params)) {
  path += '?' + toHTTPQueryString(params); // no error
}
```

`isDefined2` says "the type of `value` now excludes `undefined`".  This one works.

`isDefined1` most closely mimics what Typescript is doing with the automatic type guard `params !== undefined`.  It says "if the type of `value` is a union with `undefined`, drop the `undefined` from the union."  This one **doesn't work** and gives the same error that you had before.  The type is still `D['params']` which still includes `undefined`.

It fails because `D` is a generic so the actual type of `D['params']` is unknown.  We know that it `extends Record<string, unknown> | undefined` but we don't know what it is exactly.  So Typescript doesn't really evaluate it fully.  It doesn't see it as a union and drop the `undefined` because the actual type might not be a union.

If your function defined the `params` argument without the generic as `Record<string, unknown> | undefined` then both of these functions would work and the original `params !== undefined` would work too.

But as it stands, you can use `isDefined2` to guard the value.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wRplYm)

As a sidenote, I'm surprised that you don't get any error on assigning a default value of `undefined` to the argument `params: D['params']` since specific `D` types might not allow `undefined`.

Comment: Wow, the issue here is [ms/TS#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) and it was just fixed *yesterday*.  In TS 4.3 the original code should just start working.  Aside: that default `undefined` thing is indeed weird and unsound, and is probably caused by another [mechanism](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181#issuecomment-526916194) whereby property read/writes on generics end up substituting the generic with its constraint.

Answer (score 2):

For the longest time, TypeScript's compiler simply would not try to use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow the type of a value whose type depends on an as-yet-unspecified generic type parameter.  In your case, checking `params !== undefined` does not narrow `params` from `D["params"]` to something else.  That's frustrating for the reason you state: you just checked `params` for `undefined`, why doesn't the compiler understand?  This is the subject of a longstanding issue in GitHub: [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995).

And before yesterday, I'd have said "that's just how it is, sorry" and offered a workaround like the following: you could widen the value of generic type `D['params']` to its specific constraint type `HTTPGet['params']` and check that instead:

```
const httpGet = <D extends HTTPGet>(url: D['url'],
  _params: D['params'] = undefined): Promise<D['result']> => {
  let path = url
  const params: HTTPGet['params'] = _params; // widen to specific type here
  if (params !== undefined) {
    path += '?' + toHTTPQueryString(params); // okay now
  }
  // ...
```

---

BUT... microsoft/TypeScript#13395 was just **fixed** by the pull request [microsoft/TypeScript#43183](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43183), "Improve narrowing of generic types in control flow analysis".  In TypeScript 4.3 and above, you can expect that in certain circumstances (you can read how in the pull request notes), values of generic types like `D["params"]` will automatically be widened to their specific constraints to allow control flow analysis to proceed.

Meaning: if you run your above code as-is in a version of TypeScript after that pull request was merged, it will just work.

**Observe:** [Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-pr-43183-11#code/C4TwDgpgBAEgKnACgcQsKBeKBvAsAKCigFcAnAGwC4oBnYUgSwDsBzAosAQ1M4FsaA-NQBKEAMYB7UgBMAPHUasANCSYBrJhIDuTAHzsopCDWLlg1Yus06CAXwLTx5btABmlscAYSmUYBPgkAEViCFIQAGV6ZhYACgAPEXEpOQUYlUsNbT0ASmo01gBuAgIIeLApdEkmOigAC2BgMFR0LFkAESgy4AgmaRpYBBQ0XViyKih2gG0AcnGZgF0VLh5+ammZlb4aRcxVR1dmCGk8qERSCV4GGggO2aMTM0XdTBe8QihyNCguYDq98YGBiuKCxLb8KAAQgwWEsByOJxwBg4nD+UAA1FgZgIZhi-AEhiEwpFoqwwdxtjlClAAPQ0qBaKRqAbWBkMNGaKBiOqcVgQSEGewfIzAMi+Vxobnkv4qd5EIi8NB1CTSagzZAAUTgMyUyK5RkcTC8nHINDVzDE5GIjh1erqEE4jlIZqRH3lUBmAEExGIIGBgDM1ZwwGByAwxKjvEwaQArGg+GZ6oVEWw5OwlfDVWoNJotOARABuABYAPoAJk9fQAQhByNo9h0uvEen0BoFhsBRuN1rN5ksDCXwS6NkPdrC+hBDkxjqdzpdrrcNg9TAGFi8MG8DF90L9-rCKAYszuKWtBkgWrNRws9oOTzRih9gaCh1CYftJwicq73buMVicXi-jtkS4RRIocRDlSgoGCKYpQBKwBSrusp6oqfwqmqmrarqbr6scvTGqa5pMJa1oQLauH2o6YQunK7oet6vr+oGHrBqG4aRj4sbxkwia4cmUCpum+AEEAA)

It works!

---

I can't articulate how much of a coincidence the timing of this question is.  The issue, microsoft/TypeScript#13995, has been open for *four years*, and was fixed *yesterday*.  Of course it will take a little while for [TypeScript 4.3 to be released](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42762), so you might not be able to take advantage of the fix immediately.  But at least you know it's coming soon!